# SELECT following Friday date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to select next friday from current date.

For example:

```
Today                SELECT

Monday 6/24/2013     6/28/2013
Wednesday 6/26/2013  6/28/2013
Friday 6/28/2013     6/28/2013
Saturday 6/29/2013   7/5/2013
```

I found a few solutions close to what I want but all they do is select fridat of the day's week.

I need to use this date as a Default Value in the table column. When a user inserts a record, this column should automatically be set to the folloing Friday. Say, instead of `getdate()` in the 'Default Value or Binding', I need to put this statement that selects following Friday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select DATEADD(day,6-datepart(weekday,the_dt),the_dt) 
+ Case when datepart(weekday,the_dt) = 7 then 7 else 0 end
from table
```

Comment: This works. Do you know how to incorporate this into the Defaul Value of a table?

Comment: Yes, just use "GETDATE()" or "CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())" instead of "the_dt".  Like this: dateadd(day,(6)-datepart(weekday,getdate()),getdate())+case when datepart(weekday,getdate())=(7) then (7) else (0) end

Comment: Yea... don't know what I was thinking... Thanks!